# How to remove label after removing a component?

Tags: javascript, extjs

By removing a field in a fieldset, it's label is not removed. How can I remove it? I'm using ExtJS 2.0.2. Code follows:

```
var predicateArguments= new Ext.form.FieldSet({
    id:'predicate_arguments',
    layout:'form',
    title:'Predicate Arguments',
    defaultType:'textfield',
    autoHeight:true,
    autoWidth:true,
    autoScroll:true,
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'textarea',
            id:'description',
            fieldLabel:'Description',
            name:'description',
            readOnly:true
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {text: 'Add',
         handler:function(){
            //this will submit  the form's fields
            predicatesForm.getForm().submit();
         }},
        {text: 'Reset Fields',
         handler:function(){
            //this will reset the form's fields
            predicatesForm.getForm().reset();
         }}
        ]
})

var predicatesForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    id:'predicates-form',
    region:'center',
    split:true,
    labelAlign:'right',
    layout:'column',
    items:[availablePredicatesGrid, predicateArguments]
})

var dateField = {xtype:'datefield',
                fieldLabel:'Date',
                name:'date',
                id:'date_field'
}

var numberField = {xtype:'numberfield',
            fieldLabel:'Number',
            name:'number',
            id:'number_field'
}

//when a rule is clicked do the following...
    availablePredicatesGrid.getSelectionModel().on('rowselect', function(sm,_rowIndex,_rule){
        predicatesForm.getForm().loadRecord(_rule);
        var _ruleType= _rule.store.getAt(_rowIndex).get('type');

        //removes previous existing fields (but not labels!)
        predicateArguments.remove('date_field');
        predicateArguments.remove('number_field');

        //creates new fields according to the selected rule types
        for(i=0; i<_ruleType.length; i++){
            if(_ruleType[i]=='date'){
                predicateArguments.add(dateField);
                predicateArguments.doLayout();
            }
            else if(_ruleType[i]=='number'){
                predicateArguments.add(numberField);
                predicateArguments.doLayout();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling remove on your Ext.Element reference, do this instead:

```
Ext.getCmp('id_of_your_form_field').getEl().parent().parent().remove();
```

EDIT: this is intended for use on form field components, as it removes the wrapper div containing the label and the component

Comment: Thank you Jaitsu, but it didn't work. I tried: `Ext.get('date_field').parent().parent().remove();` but got this error in firebug:`Ext.get("date_field") is null`.

Comment: can you show the code for your form field? 'date_field' must be the ID of the field otherwise the code will not work, I tried it in ExtJS 3.3 and that works ok, maybe it's an issue with ExtJS 2, I will try it on that now

Comment: Just added it. As you can see, I have a field set, with a permanent text area, inside a form panel. I can add more fields dynamically, but removing them always leaves the fieldLabel.

Comment: as an alternative you could try `numberField.getEl().parent().parent().remove();`, and similar for `dateField`

Comment: Curiously, with that I get: `dateField.getEl is not a function`. I'm stumped... :-(

Comment: what do you get as a result of typing dateField in firebug console? also, what is output from typing Ext.Element in the firebug console?

Comment: (It seems I can't handle the comments editing function...)`>>> dateField
Object { xtype="datefield", name="date", more...}>>> Ext.Element
function()`

Comment: ok, my fault... I'll update my answer so that it works with your code

Comment: Ok, it did work for the number field :-), but not for the date field :-(. The code is exactly the same for both, only the id changes. Maybe it's a bug? I also had to add a test, so that it won't try to remove a field if it's not already there.

Comment: yeah, if the error with the dateField is "Ext.getCmp('date_field') is null" or "... is not a function" there seems like something else is going on that's conflicting with it, if it's just not behaving properly then there might a different DOM structure for datefields

Comment: Got it! :-D The number field is a text field, but the date field is also a  trigger field! So, the fix is just to add another parent() there, becoming `Ext.getCmp('date_field').getEl().parent().parent().parent().remove();`. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know extjs, but, normally, how would you do this (and how you should do this) is by simply adding the input and its label in a  or  and then, when you want to remove the input (and its label in the same time), just do:

```
obj = document.getElementById( ID-OF-ELEMENT )
obj.parentNode.html = '';
```

or just delete its parent in any other way you might find to not have empty spans lying around:

```
obj.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( obj.parentNode );
```

or, if you know that the label is just before the input, you can just do:

```
obj.parentNode.removeChild( obj.previousSibling );
```

or just combine them to suit your purpose